# Convert string "test%C3%B8%C3%B8%C3%B8.txt" to "testøø.txt"

Tags: c#

How do I translate the bytes `%C3%B8` in "testdoc%C3%B8%C3%B8%C3%B8.txt" to `ø`?

I tried the following which did not work:

```
var cont = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition?.FileName;
            
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cont);
var test = new string(bytes.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());
var yourText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: That's a URL-encoded string, not UTF8. This page is UTF8. `cont` is UTF16, as .NET strings are UTF16

Comment: Something that was mentioned in yesterday's question. UTF isn't some kind of escape sequence, it's a byte encoding. You **won't** notice any differences if you look at a string. Only the bytes behind the string are different. In most languages, (.NET, Java, Javascript, Python 3) strings are Unicode already. Trying to convert a Unicode string to Unicode won't change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother with converting it to bytes at all. As has been noted in the comments, this is URL encoding, not UTF8.

Use [`HttpUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=net-5.0) in the `System.Web` namespace:

```
string input = "testdoc%C3%B8%C3%B8%C3%B8.txt";
string output = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input);
Console.WriteLine(output); // testdocøøø.txt
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FRJXP82639)