# Read string from html code and save to file

Tags: python, utf-8, urlencode

I need to save this name to file "Lørenskog" and read again later

```
- original title on web page "Lørenskog"
titles_urls = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/a')
- in the webpage html code -> "\u00f8renskog"   
for t in titles_urls:
    if t.get_attribute('href'):
        print(t.get_attribute('href')) # it prints -> "%C3%B8renskog"
```

How do I save it to file and read like "Lørenskog" again ?I think it's in utf-8 code

EDIT :

```
import urllib.parse
sample = 'L%C3%B8renskog'
a = urllib.parse.unquote(sample)
print(a)
```

output :
Lørenskog

it's url encoded

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214367/7451892

Comment: @Andrew Ryan
I didn't find it with that title... Thank you